# React global state/props with get API calls (without Redux)

Tags: reactjs, state, global

I have a React component that runs several API calls. On intitial load the default API call is ran.

From the default API call I need to save state let's say from a property called since_launch. When subsequent API calls are ran on the component the since_launch state is lost because it's not available on subsequent API calls. I need to save the since_launch state so I can use it to determine logic on the rest of the API calls.

The application doesn't use Redux so this is not an option to save global state. As a workaround I've used local storage to save since_launch on initial load, but this doesn't feel right. Any ideas would be appreciated or clarification that what I am trying to achieve is simply not possible.

Comment: Are you updating your whole state on each different API call?

Comment: Yes updating whole state via props on each call using Recompose

Comment: And why do you do it? Is there any benefit in using it for you?

Comment: why not use redux?

Comment: because it's a relatively simple app and this would be the only use case to use Redux so seems like overkill

Comment: Very curious about future implementations of this concept. I only have one global property called "fetching" that is true if an API is happening, showing a global spinner. There is _no reason_ I should convert everything to actions, action creators, and reducers for _one property_. Redux is seeming like the only possible solution without setting up custom event listeners.

Answer (score -1):

> The application doesn't use Redux so this is not an option to save global state

Using retrieving data for multiple React components and share / manipulate it between them seems, that application need to use [flux-data stream](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), and `redux` is best implementation for it. Also, because API calls are always asynchronous, only `redux` is not enough - you should also use process manager, like [`redux-saga`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), which is de-facto standard for suggested task.

If you does not like `redux` and want to use custom solution (Which is strange), just write a Provider and simple process manager. Provider should store shared state and distribute it between component by [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) mechanism. Simple process manager should be middleware function in that full-lifecycle component, and take results of API calls in queue.
(But in result of that you will just reinvent something like this https://github.com/freeman-lab/minidux)

Anyway, if you use `redux` or not, every React components, except one - which is `Page` or `Provider` - should be functional components without own state. In another case benefits from using `React` will be lost.